# ASP.NET application implement AAD SSO with SAML

Tags: asp.net, azure, active-directory, saml

I am trying to setup a an existing ASP.NET web application to authenticate against an Azure Active Directory Account using SAML or OAUTH 2.0. Tutorials are showing me sample code only in MVC and I am wondering how I can find a sample for a non-MVC project. Is it not supported?

Comment: You need older tutorials. Take mine from 2014 https://www.wiktorzychla.com/2014/11/simplest-saml11-federated-authentication.html

Comment: Also, how do I make it that when going to any page on the site will redirect to login if not authenticated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use the below non mvc using legacy asp.net for oauth,

1.Install the OWIN middleware NuGet packages from Nuget Package:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect
Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies
Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb
```

2.Right-click on the project's root folder: > Add > New Item... > OWIN Startup class. Name it Startup.cs

3.Add OWIN and Microsoft.IdentityModel references to Startup.cs:

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Notifications;
```

4.Replace Startup class with the code below:

```
public class Startup
{
    // The Client ID is used by the application to uniquely identify itself to Azure AD.
    string clientId = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"];

    // RedirectUri is the URL where the user will be redirected to after they sign in.
    string redirectUri = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedirectUri"];

    // Tenant is the tenant ID (e.g. contoso.onmicrosoft.com, or 'common' for multi-tenant)
    static string tenant = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Tenant"];

    // Authority is the URL for authority, composed by Azure Active Directory v2 endpoint and the tenant name (e.g. https://login.microsoftonline.com/contoso.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0)
    string authority = String.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Authority"], tenant);

    /// <summary>
    /// Configure OWIN to use OpenIdConnect 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="app"></param>
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                // Sets the ClientId, authority, RedirectUri as obtained from web.config
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = authority,
                RedirectUri = redirectUri,
                // PostLogoutRedirectUri is the page that users will be redirected to after sign-out. In this case, it is using the home page
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
                Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,
                // ResponseType is set to request the id_token - which contains basic information about the signed-in user
                ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken,
                // ValidateIssuer set to false to allow personal and work accounts from any organization to sign in to your application
                // To only allow users from a single organizations, set ValidateIssuer to true and 'tenant' setting in web.config to the tenant name
                // To allow users from only a list of specific organizations, set ValidateIssuer to true and use ValidIssuers parameter 
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = false
                },
                // OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications configures OWIN to send notification of failed authentications to OnAuthenticationFailed method
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed
                }
            }
        );
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handle failed authentication requests by redirecting the user to the home page with an error in the query string
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private Task OnAuthenticationFailed(AuthenticationFailedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> context)
    {
        context.HandleResponse();
        context.Response.Redirect("/?errormessage=" + context.Exception.Message);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}

Add the parameter value as below:

<add key="ClientId" value="Enter_the_Application_Id_here" />
<add key="redirectUri" value="Enter_the_Redirect_URL_here" />
<add key="Tenant" value="common" />
<add key="Authority" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/v2.0" />
```

5.Add Login and logout button in the aspx page.

```
    <asp:Button ID="Login" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Login_Click" />
    <asp:Button ID="Loginout" runat="server" Text="Button"  OnClick="Loginout_Click"  />
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
Code-behind:

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                Label1.Text =  System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("name").Value;
            }
        }

        protected void Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Context.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
    new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" },
    OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        }

        protected void Loginout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Context.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(
               OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
               CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        }
```

Comment: Wow very comprehensive answer. I will try this out and let you know.

Comment: The redirect URI, is that an internal page I want to redirect them to in my web application? or is that something configured in AD?

Comment: And inorder for it to work do I have to publish it already to the domain that I registered in AD? What if I'm not ready to push to production but I need to test if it's working? I want to test on localhost

Comment: This is still allowing me to go to other pages without authenticating

Comment: MSFT you've been so helpful and we're almost there. Mind to answer my above comments?